# Copy a file with the variables substituted

Tags: ruby

I have a file containing substituted variables (`#{...}`) and I would like to copy it into another file, with the variables substituted by their values.

Here's what I have

```
file = File.open(@batch_file_name, "w+")
script=File.open("/runBatch.script","r")
script.each do |line|
  file.puts(line)
end
```

But this is apparently not the right way to do that. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `#{...}` in your file use ERB files.

Comment: IMHO it's better option than evaluating each line with `#{}`.

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't the right way to do it. You can't expect Ruby to magically interpret any `#{}` it encounters anywhere in your data as variable interpolation. This would (amongst other terrible side effects) yield *massive* security problems everywhere.

If you want to interpolate data into a string you'll need to `eval` it, which has its own security risks:

```
str = 'The value of x is #{x}'

puts str # The value of x is #{x}

x = "123"

puts eval "\"#{str}\"" # Thje value of x is 123
```

It's not clear *which* variables you're trying to interpolate into your data. This is almost certainly the wrong way to go about doing whatever it is your doing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok say you have a file named tmp.file that has the following text:

```
This is #{foobar}!
```

Then you can easily do the following:

```
str = ""
File.open("tmp.file", "r") do |f|
  str = f.read
end
abc = "Sparta"
puts eval('"' + str + '"')
```

And your result would be `This is Sparta!`

But as already suggested you should go with a real template solution like ERB. Then you would use your files like views in Rails. Instead of `This is #{foobar}.` you would have `This is <%= foobar %>.`